# Refresh appended element without reloading the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, append

I am getting animals from a json file randomly and splitting letters into a span and appending it a `.wrapper` div.

But when i reload json, new animal appends there and old one doesn't dissappear.

How can i split letter using `html()` methtod or how can i reload specific div without refreshing the whole page ?

Click refresh button you see a new animal name appends the div (as we expect).
I am just looking for the solution with using `append()` method or not.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9wsjf90r/)**

```
function loadJson() {

  $.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boennemann/animals/master/words.json', function(data) {

    var s = data[Math.floor((Math.random() * data.length))];

    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

      var $span = $("<span>", {
        class: " letter" + i
      }).appendTo(".wrapper");;
      $span.append(s[i]);
    }
  });

}

loadJson();

$("button").click(function() {
  loadJson();
});
```

Comment: call `$('.wrapper').empty()` before your cycle.

Comment: Use `.html()` instead of `.append()`

Comment: Aa. empty() method worked! @Maxx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use $('.classname').empty() before append..
https://jsfiddle.net/9wsjf90r/1/

```
function loadJson() {

  $.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boennemann/animals/master/words.json', function(data) {

    var s = data[Math.floor((Math.random() * data.length))];
$('.wrapper').empty();
    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

      var $span = $("<span>", {
        class: " letter" + i
      }).appendTo(".wrapper");;

      $span.append(s[i]);
    }
  });

}

loadJson();

$("button").click(function() {
  loadJson();
});
```